# Grouping ArrayList into JSON Arrays/Objects

Tags: java, json, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a file structure in a database, with path and filename as columns and looking to group them together, but not sure how to do that. Here is a stripped down version of what I am using currently:

```
//in this example, list is the returned data
JSONArray jList1 = new JSONArray();
for (int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){
    Object[] fileObj = (Object[])list.get(a);
    String folder = (String)fileObj[0];
    String filename = (String)fileObj[1];
    JSONObject jObj1 = new JSONObject();
    jObj1.put("path",folder);
    jObj1.put("filename",filename);
    jList1.add(jObj1);
}
response.getWriter().write(jList1.toJSONString());
```

This puts everything into the same JSONArray. Here is an example of the output:

```
[
    {
        path: "/a",
        filename: ""
    },
    {
        path: "/a",
        filename: "file1.png"
    },
    {
        path: "/a/b",
        filename: ""
    },
    {
        path: "/a/b",
        filename: "file2.png"
    },
    {
        path: "/a/b",
        filename: "file3.png"
    },
    {
        path: "/a/c",
        filename: ""
    },
    {
        path: "/a/c",
        filename: "file4.jpg",
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        filename: "file5.jpg",
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        filename: "file6.jpg",
    }
]
```

I'd like to have it like:

```
[
    {
        path: "/a",
        filename: ""
        files: [
            {
                path: "/a/b",
                filename: ""
                files: [
                    {
                        path: "/a/b",
                        filename: "file2.png"
                    },
                    {

                        path: "/a/b",
                        filename: "file3.png"
                    }
                ]
            },          
            {
                path: "/a/c",
                filename: ""
                files: [
                    {
                        path: "/a/c",
                        filename: "file4.jpg",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "/a",
                filename: "file1.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        filename: "file5.jpg",
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        filename: "file6.jpg",
    }
]
```

Now I could do this knowing the exact number of levels, but not sure how to do with an unknown number of levels of the tree. There are other properties in each object that I have taken out for the example, which is why I am not just putting the filename itself in the array.

I left out the database structure as don't think its really needed. Only thing might be how its ordered, which I have:

```
order by (CASE WHEN path='/' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), path, filename
```

Basically have folders at the top and files at the bottom in each level.

Can someone put me on the right track to structuring the JSON the way I am looking for? I know it will have to be some sort of storing records comparing to previous ones, but just can't seem to figure out how to structure it. I had thought about having different queries for each directory, but that will cause a lot of hits to the database, resulting in performance issues.

Comment: Why do you need to nest them like that, I feel any entry with just a file path is superfluous since that info exist for any item in that path, that  is there is no point to have `"/a/b", ""` when you have `"/a/b","file2.png"` and then you can extract the parent path from the second item.

Comment: I need to nest them for the final output. The template nests them like that for the display. I understand what you are saying about the not having folder listed like that, but understand that I have that there because the folder has more information in the object like modified date, number of files, etc. I stripped it out for simplicity purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by creating a ResourceTree class:

```
public class ResourceTree {
    private String parentPath;
    private List<ResourceTree> childrenItems;
    private JSONObject jObj1;

    public ResourceTree() {
        this.parentPath = "";
        this.childrenItems = new ArrayList<ResourceTree>();
    }

    public String getParentPath() {
        return parentPath;
    }

    public void setParentPath(String parentPath) {
        this.parentPath = parentPath;
    }

    public JSONObject getResourceObj() {
        return jObj1;
    }

    public void setResourceObj(JSONObject jObj1) {
        this.jObj1 = jObj1;
    }

    public List<ResourceTree> getChildrenItems() {
        return childrenItems;
    }

    public void setChildrenItems(List<ResourceTree> childrenItems) {
        this.childrenItems = childrenItems;
    }

    public void addChildrenItem(ResourceTree childrenItem){
        if(!this.childrenItems.contains(childrenItem))
            this.childrenItems.add(childrenItem);
    }

    public JSONArray getFileList() {
        JSONArray jList1 = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject();
        List rtChilds = getChildrenItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < rtChilds.size(); i++) {
            ResourceTree rt = (ResourceTree)rtChilds.get(i);
            jObj2 = rt.getResourceObj();
            if (rt.getChildrenItems().size() > 0) {
                jObj2.put("files",rt.getFileList());
            }
            jList1.add(jObj2);
        }
        return jList1;
    }
}
```

From there, I create a ResourceTree for every item and added to the child items where applicable.

```
//list is an ArrayList of objects
if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
    Map<String, ResourceTree> hm = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (int b = 0; b < list.size(); b++){
        Object[] fileObj = (Object[])list.get(b);
        if (fileObj != null) {
            String folder = (String)fileObj[0];
            String parentFolder = folder;
            String fn = (String)fileObj[1];
            String type = "";
            if (fn.equals("")) {
                parentFolder = folder.substring(0,folder.lastIndexOf("/"));
            }
            jObj1 = new JSONObject();
            jObj1.put("path",folder);
            jObj1.put("filename",fn);   

            ResourceTree rt = new ResourceTree();
            rt.setResourceObj(jObj1);
            rt.setParentPath(parentFolder);
            if (fn.equals("")) {
                hm.put(folder,rt);
            }
            ResourceTree rtParent;
            if (hm.containsKey(parentFolder)){
                rtParent = hm.get(parentFolder);
            } else {
                rtParent = new ResourceTree();
                rtParent.setParentPath(parentFolder.substring(0,parentFolder.lastIndexOf("/")));
                hm.put(parentFolder,rtParent);
            }
            rtParent.addChildrenItem(rt);
        }
    }
    List<ResourceTree> DX = new ArrayList<ResourceTree>();
        for (ResourceTree rt : hm.values()) {
            //path is the top level folder specified
            if (rt.getParentPath().equals(path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/")))) {
                jList1.addAll(rt.getFileList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to try to solve your problem.

First create a file to store the values of each file / directory. Here's the example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Archive implements Comparable<Archive> {

    private String path;
    private String filename;
    List<Archive> files;

    public Archive(String path, String filename) {
        this.path = path;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.files = new ArrayList<Archive>();
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public List<Archive> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Path = "+ path + ", Filename = "+ filename;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Archive archive) {
        return getPath().compareTo(archive.getPath());
    }

}
```

Now let's create the method that will read your folder and create the Archive class list:

```
public static void listFilesFromFolder(final File folder, final List<Archive> listArchive) {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String path = file.getPath().replace(mainFolderPath, "").replace(file.getName(), "");
            Archive archive = new Archive(path, file.getName());
            listArchive.add(archive);
        }
    }

    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String path = file.getPath().replace(mainFolderPath, "");
            Archive archive = new Archive(path, "");
            listArchive.add(archive);
            listFilesFromFolder(file, archive.getFiles());
        }
    }
}
```

Next we will create the method that converts a List to JSON.

```
public static String listToJSON(List<Archive> listArchive) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(listArchive);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

And finally we will create the Main method to run our application:

```
public class Test {

    final static String mainFolderPath = "c:\\MyFolder";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File(mainFolderPath);

        List<Archive> listArchive = new ArrayList<Archive>();

        listFilesFromFolder(folder, listArchive);

        Collections.sort(listArchive);

        System.out.println( listToJSON(listArchive) );
    }
}
```

For information only, follow the imports that were used:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

I hope I've helped.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I went away before I could review this. Thanks for taking the time with this. This structure requires to have to loop through files in each folder, which would be multiple queries in my case.